# How to input Response to Button in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, view, console.log

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <form>
    <label>Enter Currency: <input type="text"></label>
  
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

app.vue

```
<script>
  //eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  import axios from 'axios'
export default {
 
  data: () => ({
    
    cryptos: [],
    errors: []

  }),

  created () {

    axios.get('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=EUR')
    .then(response => {
    this.cryptos = response.data
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
  })
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

I got the following code in Vue.js and I want when I press Submit Button  refresh the page and return the console.log(Response). I tried using this code but it returns me blank page even though when I go to chrome console I can see that the Values of Response are there but How can I display them to the page ?

Comment: I take it you're not using `.vue` SFC files then - how are you initialising vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion **:**

- You can use input type as `button` instead of `submit` to prevent the auto submit behavior.
- Attach click event on the button and on `click` make the axios call to get the response and then bind that in the same page below the button.

But If You want to show the response in an another route then there are two possible solutions :

1. Set the response data in the Vuex store on click and then fetch in the page where you want to show.
2. pass the currency on click as a route param and then make an API call in the route where you want to display the results.

Here is the demo of how you can get the results and bind in the same component **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      apiEndPoint : 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=',
      apiData: null,
      currency: 'EUR'
    }
  },
  created() {
    // This will invoke when page load with a default currency. here is am setting 'EUR'
    this.getData(this.currency);
  },
  methods: {
    getData(currency) {
      axios.get(`${this.apiEndPoint}${currency}`).then((response) => {
        this.apiData = response.data
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.1/axios.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <label>Enter Currency: <input type="text" v-model="currency"></label>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" @click="getData(currency)"/>
  </form>
  <p>Bitcoin Value is : {{ apiData?.data?.amount }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot it really helped me understand how to do it . Last thing how can i make the json output look better?

Comment: @TakisParas To pretify the json output i already added `<pre>` tag.

Comment: yes i saw it i literally mean returning only BTC,AMOUNT,CURRENCY without showing the other structure of json

Comment: @TakisParas You can access that by using `apiData.data.base`

Comment: i already did that but when i change it ,it destroyed the whole form

Comment: i want to make it something like this       <pre> <p>Bitcoin Value is: {{ apiData.data.amount   }}</p></pre>              but in chrome console it says that i cant read properties of Null data

Comment: @TakisParas Got it! For that you have to use Optional chaining (?.) oeprator. I updated the code snippet. You can check now.

Comment: one last question if u can asnwer me how can i store the amount value into a list every time i press the submit button?

Comment: @TakisParas In that case you can declare an array property (`amountList: []`) in data object and then inside the axios response .. you can do like this `this.amountList.push(response.data.data.amount)`

Comment: yes I already found this but I cant find how I can store them every time I press the button like I press 1 time i store the value I press second time I store the value

Comment: sry for the variety of questions but im new and now i learning how to code in vue.js now im stucked to show on my template the value i get from amountList each time i press the button

Comment: @TakisParas You can iterate array in template using `v-for` directive. Please check the vue documentation of `v-for` for better understanding.

Comment: hi i come back to you because u are the only here willing to asnwer i had an issue with my programm  on my axios call i want the output response amount in my list to get delayed any idea how to do this? I need to delay this like 1 minute per axios call

Comment: @TakisParas This is not a right place to discuss on a seperate question. You can ask a seperate question with all the details/issue you are facing. Then i can look into that.